# В Jupyter Notebook ошибка импорта tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, импорт, командная-строка

Изначально код работал, но при повторном его перезапуске в блокноте (Restart&Run All) получаю ошибку импорта ImportError для tensorflow следующего содержания:

**cannot import name 'export_saved_model' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model'**

Как возможное решение проблемы, деинсталировать в командной строке библиотеку с тем, чтобы заново ее установить. Попытка сделать это через conda результата не дала (застревал на этапе solving environment: указатель вращался, но затем ничего не происходило). Решения добился с помощью pip. И получил вторую ошибку - теперь с другим импортом:

**cannot import name 'tf2' from 'tensorflow.python' (unknown location)**

Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, сначала "ругался" tensorflow, после его "починки" - keras, но в итоге помогло последовательное выполнение команд `pip uninstall tensorflow`, `pip uninstall keras` и после них - повторная установка модулей.
Были эксперименты с виртуальным окружением, но эти решения оказались лишними